# threejs import GLTF: why does the model show differently?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to threejs. I Exported a model in GLTF from Blender and imported to threejs(v93).
But the rendering effect in threejs is quite different with the one in blender.
How can I fix it?

the threejs code is:

```
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load(url,function(gltf){
                let model = gltf.scene;
                model.scale.set(3.5,3.5,3.5);
                model.traverse(function(child){
                    if(child.isMesh){                       
                        child.material.emissive =  child.material.color;
                        child.material.emissiveMap = child.material.map;
                        
                    }
                })
                model.name = 'truck';
                scene.add(model);
            })
```

[difference between threejs and blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peBnk.png)

Comment: Why are you setting the material's emissive property to its color (and emissive map to its texture)? That might be messing up your lighting.

Comment: It's showing up differently because with Three.js, you have to manually add lighting. [Here's a quick demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_hemisphere) on how to illuminate a scene, but the possibilities are endless.

Comment: If not setting the material's emissive property to its color, the imported model would appear compeletely black. @Robert May

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I'll read that first. @Marquizzo

Comment: @Marquizzo I added a spotlight to the model  because I think it's better for an interior scene. But it seems that I must give the spotlight strong intensity around  4~5 to make the model look better. But it will influence the whole scene. Are there any ways to do that?